# Remove reverberation between different audio sources for Pulse Audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I recently discovered the ability to output sound to multiple sources using the combine-sink module, as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379376/how-to-achieve-automated-simultaneous-outputs-with-pipewire)

Although I'm having fun trying to configure levels, muting, etc between the various outputs  my laptop has (and how seemingly nonsensical this process is), one thing I'm wrestling with is a timing disparity between an auxiliary device and my laptop's built in speakers, which creates a bit of an echo with any sort of volume.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way (software, another module, config, etc.) to adjust/buffer outputs to cancel out this echo/reverb effect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pop!_OS is off-topic here.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Pop!_OS is a fork of Ubuntu.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and **official** derivatives are on-topic here.